# Get application insight data with applicaiton ID and secret

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token, insight

So in order to get the insight data for my application I need the access_token with read_insight_data permission. However I don't want a user interaction during the process. Can I get my application's insight data with just application ID and secret?

thanks,
Green

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got it.

First, get client(AKA application) access token:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=${client_id}&client_secret=${client_secret}&grant_type=client_credentials
```

facebook will return something looks like:

```
access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Second Use that returned token you can get the application insight data:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/${client_id}/insights/?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: This does not work for me - I also got the app access token, the properared the call and tried in a browser. I get this:
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 1
   }
}